# Javascript | Odd Array Behavior - Parsing a Combined Array vs a Pre Definied Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, push

I'm experiencing some odd behavior with arrays. I don't understand what's happening. If I create two arrays...

```
var a = [0,0,1,0];
var b = [0,2, 1,2];
```

And combine them...

```
combineChars();
function combineChars(){
   combo.push(a);
   combo.push(b);
}
```

I end up with an array...

```
combo = [0,0,1,0,0,2,1,2];
```

However, if I attempt to split the array into two separate arrays It doesn't split as expected.

```
function splitArray(a){
    console.log("splitArray("+a+")"); //splitArray(0,0,1,0,0,2,1,2)
    for (i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        if ((i+2)%2==0) {
            rSplit.push(a[i]);
        } else {
            cSplit.push(a[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log("rSplit = " + rSplit); //rSplit = 0,0,1,0
    console.log("cSplit = " + cSplit); //cSplit = 0,2,1,2
}
```

expected...

```
console.log("rSplit = " + rSplit); //rSplit = 0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1
console.log("cSplit = " + cSplit); //cSplit = 0,2,1,2,0,0,2,2
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/taylorRichie/yrzrqm38/4/

As you can see from the fiddle, if I create the array "co" instead of combining two arrays, it behaves as expected.

???

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Richie

Comment: your first bit of code looks suspect. `var combo[]; combo.push(a); combo.push(b);` will generate a *nested* array (combo.length will be 2, the first element is the entire array `a`, the second the entire array `b`), not a flat array like you're claiming (hit F12, check for yourself).

Comment: Are you *certain* you end up with `[0,0,1,0,0,2,1,2];` after combining that way? You should end up with `combo` containing 2 elements, both of them arrays (a and b).

Comment: Why do you expect the results which you stated for `rSplit` and `cSplit`?

Comment: Ahhh... I need to cycle through the content of **a**, and **b** and push them individually?

Comment: going a long way around using methods like concat() that will do this for you

Comment: Argh... yes, concat() - Man, taking 2 years away from programming really shows... Thanks Everyone, I have figured it out with your help.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Why are you doing `if ((i+2)%2==0)`? Whenever `i+2` is even, so is `i`. This means there is no reason for the `+2`. 2) Do you really want to "split" the odd-indexed elements from the even-indexed ones?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - I do... I'm actually programming an ARDUINO powered LED matrix through a Node.JS server. The separating of odd/even to give me direct access to row/column.

Comment: Sounds good. Also `console.log("splitArray("+a+")");` gives misleading output since it only gives the elements of the array and does not show any nesting of lists. You should also consider doing `console.log(a)` on a separate line. For some reason the JavaScript designers decided that converting an array to a string should not contain any syntax which indicates the array itself (such as brackets around the list of elements).

Answer (score 1):

Given an empty `combo` array, and your `a` and `b` arrays,

```
combo.push(a);
combo.push(b);
```

does not push the *elements* of `a` and `b` to `combo`, as you claim, but instead, pushes the arrays themselves, making `combo` an array with 2 elements, both elements being the original `a` and `b` arrays themselves.

If you use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead of [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), your `combo` array will be constructed as you originally expected.

i.e. change your `combineChars` function to the following:

```
function combineChars(){
   combo = combo.concat(a);
   combo = combo.concat(b);
}
```

*Note that you need to reassign `combo`, because `concat` does not mutate the original array, but returns a new one.*

Comment: or just `combo = a.concat(b);` since concat doesn't modify the original arrays.

Comment: @JimboJonny correct in this case, I just wanted to follow the logic of OP as close as possible, to highlight the differences. (This is closer to the general semantics of "pushing" values - it would also work if combo was not empty)

Answer (score 0):

Look to built in `Array.prototype` methods first

```
var rSplit = [].concat(a).concat(b);
var lSplit = [].concat(b).concat(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are **not** ending up with an array combo which is those 8 elements. You're ending up with an array combo which is 2 elements, each being their respective original 4 element arrays. Arrays can hold other arrays as elements. Push adds something as an element...it does not concatenate arrays together.

You need to use `.concat` to actually combine two arrays.

`combo = a.concat(b);`